# Pass the type of the requesting class to the dependency injected class in .NET 6?

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, .net-6.0

How do I do the following code, but instead of `x.GetType()` which returns `ServiceProviderEngineScope` it returns the requesting class's type (e.g., `HomeController`).

```
builder.Services.AddScoped<IMyService>((IServiceProvider x) => new MyService(x.GetType()));
```

To try and clarify a little more,

```
public class HomeController
{
    private readonly IMyService MyService;

    // I want HomeController's type to be passed to the instance of IMyService since it's the class requesting it.
    public HomeController(IMyService myService) 
    {
         MyService = myService;
    }
}
```

MyService would look something like this:

```
public class MyService : IMyService
{
    public MyService(Type requestingType)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"This service was requested by {requestingType.Name}."); // For example.
    }
}
```

Comment: what do you mean as "requesting class"?

Comment: If the `HomeController` is requesting an instance of `IMyService` in its contstructor I want the type of `HomeController`.

Comment: So, do you need to pass `new MyService(typeof(HomeController))` into the `HomeController` constructor?

Comment: @Serg if so, it would be an anti-pattern

Comment: ah, okay: now it's clear what you're asking. I don't think there's a way to achieve.

Comment: Maybe look at how logging works in DI, although you're still expected to identify yourself (i.e. request a `IMyService<HomeController>` if you're the `HomeController`). It doesn't attempt to prevent you requesting the wrong type of service.

Comment: With logging, do they inject the factory instead of the logger? Is that how they're doing it?

Comment: AFAIK you instantiate a specialized logger via a factory. The specialization (i.e. the type of the hosting class as generic param) is up to you.

Comment: Okay, that sounds good enough for what I need. I appreciate the assistance. If you want to make an answer saying/doing that I'll gladly except it.

Comment: What you are looking for is called context-based injection and this is not supported in MS.DI. More mature DI Containers usually do contain a feature like this, but with MS.DI, you often have to go through several hoops and have to change your design to achieve such a thing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Build-in DI allows registering open generic types, so if you can change the interface to be generic one, then:

```cs
public interface IMyService<T>
{
}

public class MyService<T> : IMyService<T>
{
    public MyService()
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"This service was requested by {typeof(T)}."); // For example.
    }
}
```

With the following registration:

```cs
services.AddTransient(typeof(IMyService<T><>), typeof(MyService<T><>));
```

And then you can resolve closed type in the controller:

```cs
public class HomeController
{
    private readonly IMyService<HomeController> MyService;

    public HomeController(IMyService<HomeController> myService) 
    {
         MyService = myService;
    }
}
```

Basically the same as with `ILogger<T>` interface.

Comment: `services.AddTransient(typeof(IGeneric<>), typeof(MyGeneric<>)); ` I think you meant `services.AddTransient(typeof(IMyService<>), typeof(MyService<>)); ` - but good answer! Exactly what I thought - just like `ILogger<T>`

Comment: Hmm I think a "pointless" generic is probably better than having to deal with all of that factory business. I like it better than the alternative, thank you. I hadn't considered doing this.

Comment: @Jamiec yes, exactly. Fixed, thank you!

Answer (score 2):

There's no real way to do it completely dynamically, but there are a few workarounds:

The first is to change your service to use generics to retrieve the type and register a separate instance of the service for each type that will be requesting it.
e.g.

Change MyService to something like the following:

```
public class MyService<TRequestor> : IMyService
{
    public MyService()
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"This service was requested by {typeof(TRequestor).Name}."); 
    }
}
```

Then register it with DI

```
services.AddScoped<MyService<HomeController>>();
```

Finally in HomeController:

```
public class HomeController
{
    private readonly IMyService<HomeController> _myService;

    public HomeController(IMyService<HomeController> myService) 
    {
         this._myService = myService;
    }
```

}

This is an alright solution for small applications, but a more scalable way to do this, would be to put your service creation behind a factory.

It would look something like the following:

Your MyService can stay the same, but the factory is used to new it up, instead of relying on the DI container.

The factory could look like this:

```
public MyServiceFactory
{
    public MyService<T> GetMyService<T>()
    {
        return new MyService<T>();
    }
}
```

Then in HomeController:

```
public HomeController
{
    
    private readonly MyService<HomeController> _myService;

    public HomeController(MyServiceFactory myServiceFactory)
    {
        this._myservice = myServiceFactory.Get<HomeController>();
    }
}
```

Naturally, you'd add the factory to the DI container instead of adding the service directly.
This approach allows you to have a bit more control over your service instantiation while keeping your dependencies inverted and your code DRY.

Comment: Check out my answer - there are easier ways to achieve that if interface can be made generic.